# Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to D = \mathbb C \setminus \{0 \}$ be a continuous closed curve. Show that $\gamma \approx \sigma$ in $D$ for..

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, homotopy-theory

> Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to D = \mathbb C \setminus \{0 \}$ be a continuous closed curve. Show that $\gamma \approx \sigma$ in $D$ for some curve $\sigma$ whose trace is contained in $S^1$.

Hello, I started doing an introductory course to complex analysis and I came across this exercise. I got a tip telling me to use $\gamma(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ to build $\sigma$. However, despite the tip, I'm still pretty lost. I would greatly appreciate any other tips.

Thanks.

Comment: *Morera*, I think. What do you mean by $\approx$? My guess is that you meant $\gamma$ is *homotopic to* $\sigma$. It might be more conventional to write this as $\gamma\simeq\sigma$. One word: scale.

Comment: If $\gamma(t)\neq0$ for all $t$, then you can take $H(t,s)=\frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|^s}$. For $s=0$, $H(t,s)=\gamma(t)$, while for $s=1$, $H(t,s)\in S^1$.

Comment: What could this have to do with Morera's theorem? MT says that if certain integrals vanish then a certain function is holomorphic - there are no integrals or even _functions_ in the problem.

Comment: The standard thing you should think of is this: Given a nonzero vector, is there a natural way to get a unit vector? Please do not use irrelevant tags ("trace" is for trace of matrices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\space\space\space$Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}/\{0\}$ be a continuous closed curve.

Define $\sigma$ thusly;

$$\sigma(t) := {\gamma(t)\over |\gamma(t)|} $$

Now, consider the following homotopy $H:[0,1]\times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}/\{0\}$

$$H(t,s):= (1-s)\cdot\gamma(t)+s\cdot\sigma(t)$$

Which clearly gives us;

$$H(t,0)=\gamma(t)$$
$$H(t,1)=\sigma(t)$$

So these curves are, indeed, homotopic on the given domain.

Additionally, we can see that;

$$\sigma(t)={\gamma(t)\over |\gamma(t)|}=z \implies |z|=\left|{\gamma(t)\over |\gamma(t)|}\right|=1$$

So the entire image of $\sigma(t)$ has modulus equal to $1$. Therefore, the trace of our curve is certainly contained in $S^1$, as required.

Comment: OP should check that indeed $H(t,s)\ne0$ for any $s,t\in[0,1]$.